# How to replace the contents of an element?

Tags: vue.js

I use VueJS to set the content of elements via data defined in a `Vue` instance:

```
<p id="hello">
    {{ message }}
</p>
```

How can I completely replace the content of such an element (discarding the previous content, in the case above `{{ message }}`), to turn the `<p>`into for instance

```
<p id="hello">
     The replacement text
</p>
```

In jQuery I would have called `$("#hello").html("the replacement text");` - what is the equivalent in VueJS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vue is `MVVM` so you map data to the view. You can replace HTML with `v-html`, but your html would have to be stored in your `vm` and this isn't recommended:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <span v-html="message"></span>
  <button v-on:click="newHtml">Change HTML</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    newHtml() {
      this.message = '<p style="color:red;">New Message</p>';
    }
  },
  data: {
    message: "<p>Message</p>"
  }
});
```

Heres the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e07tj1sa/

Really, with vue you should try to move away from thinking in jQuery, they are conceptually different. In vue the preferred method is to build up your app with reusable components not to directly affect the html in the DOM.

https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#What-are-Components

Comment: This is correct, but why use `v-html` when he only wants to change the text? Use `{{message}}` and then set `this.message = 'The replacement text'`. `v-html` allows XSS!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that.Basically you have to directly change the property into data object

https://jsbin.com/wexehasege/1/edit?html,js,output

So you can create new method that change message, and then call it after instance is created - with created() lifecycle hook.

Comment: I clarified my question: I would like to completely replace the content of the element (`<p>` in the example) and not chnage the value of `{{ message }}`

Comment: First thing you have to think about is VueJS is not jQuery.
VueJS VMVM - so that's mean you have some kind of model in each app - so you have to define some initial data.
What you can do here is maybe using v-if, and then define some boolean value into data object.